# Spring-Data JPA: InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException for @Transactional

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, transactional

I run a Spring Boot Application wiht `@EnableTransactionManagement` and want to use `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` for some database queries.

But I receive a confusing error message.
I'm using Spring, Spring Boot and and Spring Data JPA.

MySpringBootApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("com.deutscheboerse.regrephub")
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.deutscheboerse.regrephub")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.deutscheboerse.regrephub")
@Slf4j
public class MySpringBootApplication
{
   ... Some @Autowired variables ...

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      SpringApplication.run(MySpringBootApplication.class, args);
   }

   ... 
}
```

MySpringBootApplicationConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableEncryptableProperties
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableAsync
@Slf4j
public class MySpringBootApplicationConfiguration
{
   ... Some @Autowired variables ...

   @Bean
   @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
   public DataSource dataSource()
   {
      return DataSourceBuilder
            .create(this.dataSourceProperties.getClassLoader())
            .url(this.dataSourceProperties.getUrl())
            .username(this.dataSourceProperties.getUsername())
            .password(this.dataSourceProperties.getPassword())
            .build();
    }

    ...
}
```

MyBeanDao.java

```
@Repository
public interface MyBeanDao extends JpaRepository<MyBeanData, Long>
{
    @QueryHints(value = @QueryHint(name = HINT_FETCH_SIZE, value = "" + Integer.MIN_VALUE))
    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE", nativeQuery = true)
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    Stream<MyBeanData> streamAll();
}
```

MyBeanService.java

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class MyBeanService extends AbstractService
{
    @Autowired
    public MyBeanService(...)
    {
       ...
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)
    public void handleRequest(Object request, Message msg)
    {
       try (Stream<MyBeanData> data = myBeanDao.streamAll())
       {
          ...
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
          ...
       }
    }
}
```

When I run my SpringBootApplication I will receive the following log messages / errors:

```
[TransactionInterceptor:474] Getting transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.streamAll]
[TransactionInterceptor:517] Completing transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.streamAll] after exception: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: You're trying to execute a streaming query method without a surrounding transaction that keeps the connection open so that the Stream can actually be consumed. Make sure the code consuming the stream uses @Transactional or any other way of declaring a (read-only) transaction.
[RuleBasedTransactionAttribute:131] Applying rules to determine whether transaction should rollback on org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: You're trying to execute a streaming query method without a surrounding transaction that keeps the connection open so that the Stream can actually be consumed. Make sure the code consuming the stream uses @Transactional or any other way of declaring a (read-only) transaction.
[RuleBasedTransactionAttribute:148] Winning rollback rule is: null
[RuleBasedTransactionAttribute:153] No relevant rollback rule found: applying default rules
```

First JPA opens a transaction and close it immediately with an exception, that I want to execute a streaming query method without a surrounding transaction.
Does someone had this before?!

Comment: Why do you have the propagation to Supports? Please try this: 1) remove propagation metadata from the Service (leave the default one) 2) remove the @Transactional from the Repository interface (not needed). Run your code and see if it's ok

Comment: Which your recommended changes I receive this error:

`[TransactionInterceptor:483] Don't need to create transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.streamAll]: This method isn't transactional.`

Comment: Followed by the exception: 
`org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: You're trying to execute a streaming query method without a surrounding transaction that keeps the connection open so that the Stream can actually be consumed. Make sure the code consuming the stream uses @Transactional or any other way of declaring a (read-only) transaction.`

Comment: that does not make much sense.. can you remove @Transactional from everywhere in this particular call hierarchy and try again? Here are java 8 examples using the Stream in repository https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/jpa/java8

Comment: I removed all annotations with `@Transactional` and get same log messages / errors as above.

Comment: is MyBeanData an entity? I am not sure if the "native" part of the query is not causing problems. Which implementation of JPA are you using? I assume it's Hibernate. You have to wrap the method that calls the repository in a read only transaction. Please take a look at the provided link with examples above. Strip any additional modifications if possible (e.g. QueryHints etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it!

It was a problem with the spring context.

When I initialize MyBeanService, I stored the bean into an HashMap with an corresponding request-object.

```
dispatcher.put(MyBeanRequest.class, this);
...
((MyAbstractService) dispatcher.get(MyBeanRequest.class).handleRequest(...);
```

it works, when I search for the bean in the spring context:

```
dispatcher.put(MyBeanRequest.class, this.getClass());
...
((MyAbstractService) appContext.getBean(dispatcher.get(requestObject.getClass()))).handleRequest(...);
```