# Spring Data JPA Stream and Kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, java-stream

I'm trying to use the JPA Streams in my Kotlin project and I keep getting `You're trying to execute a streaming query method without a surrounding transaction that keeps the connection open so that the Stream can actually be consumed. Make sure the code consuming the stream uses @Transactional or any other way of declaring a (read-only) transaction.`

I know the pre-requisites of using Streams and I have already surrounded my code with `@Transactional` and close the Stream yet it doesn't work.

Here's my code:

```
@Repository
interface MyRepository : JpaRepository<SomeValue, Long> {
    @QueryHints(value = [
        QueryHint(name = HINT_FETCH_SIZE, value = "100"),
        QueryHint(name = HINT_CACHEABLE, value = "false"),
        QueryHint(name = READ_ONLY, value = "true")
    ])
    @Query(
        """select s.id, s.name
            from Some s
            """,
        nativeQuery = true
    )
    fun findSomeValues(
    ): Stream<SomeValue>
}


@Service
class Someservice(
    private val myRepository: MyRepository,
    ...
) {
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    fun retrieveSomeValues(
    ): SomeDto {
        
        val someDto =
            myRepository.findSomeValues().use {
                it.map { SomeObject(it.id, it.name) }
                ....
            }

        return someDto
    }
}
```

Edit:

Relevant dependencies:

```
Spring Boot: 2.3.4.RELEASE
Kotlin: 1.3.72
Spring-boot-starter-data-jpa
```

Comment: `@Transactional` only works if the class and method are `public` and non-final.

Comment: both the class and method are public and not final.

Comment: I was asking because the code doesn't make use of the `open` keyword.

Comment: I'm using `org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.spring` so it should make all classes open at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

is it possible that you are not closing the stream in the end ? you should try the following:

```
@Transactional
void someMethod() {

  try (Stream result = repository.streamAllBy()) {
    // … processing goes here
  }
}
```

> A Stream potentially wraps underlying data store-specific resources
> and must, therefore, be closed after usage. You can either manually
> close the Stream by using the close() method or by using a Java 7
> try-with-resources block, as shown in the following example:

Comment: I'm using Kotlin's `use`(https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/use.html) which is an equivalent of Java's try-with-resources. I also tried with manually closing the stream but none worked.

Comment: well i asked because i wasnt sure about kotlin's use, thats why i asked for the try, but if you manually closed it, then it wouldnt solve it anyway. could you maybe add the following information: your relevant imports, how you declare your repository, kotlin version ?

Comment: I have just added those details. Let me know if there's something else.

Comment: @zhaider have you tried adding @ Transactional to class level instead of function level?

Comment: Yes, I already tried that.

Comment: the only other thing you could check is making service an @component and/or if you have the correct transaction import.

Comment: I don't think it would matter much as I already have `@Service` annotation but I still gave it a try and same problem. What's strange when I change the log level to TRACE I see an entry saying `No need to create transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findSomeValues]: This method is not transactional.` and then it throws an exception.

Comment: check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48322731/spring-data-jpa-invaliddataaccessapiusageexception-for-transactional seems like it might be of use to you

Comment: I have tried everything, nothing works. It's funny because everything works if I change the type from `Stream` to `List` in the repository function but that's not what I want.

Comment: did you check out the link i sent you?

Comment: Yes. I also reduced the function to a bare minimum with just a simple findAllById without any custom or native query yet the problem remains.

Comment: then i think you should make a new question or put up a bounty, bcs i cannot help you further.